# Spark & Scala: saveAsTextFile() exception

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I'm new to Spark & Scala and I got exception after calling saveAsTextFile(). Hope someone can help...

Here is my input.txt:

```
Hello World, I'm a programmer 
Hello World, I'm a programmer
```

This is the info after running "spark-shell" on CMD:

```
C:\Users\Nhan Tran>spark-shell
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Spark context Web UI available at http://DLap:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1526374303208).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.3.0
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_172)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

Here are my codes:

```
scala> val inputfile = sc.textFile("input.txt")
scala> val counts = inputfile.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_+_);
scala> counts.toDebugString
scala> counts.cache()
scala> counts.saveAsTextFile("output")
```

Everything works until I called counts.saveAsTextFile("output"), here are my exception:

```
2018-05-15 14:28:27 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 4)
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Ljava/lang/String;JJJI)Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;
            at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Native Method)
            at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileOutputStreamWithMode(NativeIO.java:559)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:219)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:398)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:804)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:123)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapRedWriteConfigUtil.initWriter(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:224)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:118)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:79)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    2018-05-15 14:28:27 ERROR Executor:91 - Exception in task 1.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 5)
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Ljava/lang/String;JJJI)Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;
            at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Native Method)
            at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileOutputStreamWithMode(NativeIO.java:559)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:219)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:398)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:804)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:123)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapRedWriteConfigUtil.initWriter(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:224)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:118)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:79)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    2018-05-15 14:28:27 WARN  TaskSetManager:66 - Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 4, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Ljava/lang/String;JJJI)Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;
            at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Native Method)
            at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileOutputStreamWithMode(NativeIO.java:559)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:219)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:398)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:804)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:123)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapRedWriteConfigUtil.initWriter(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:224)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:118)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:79)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    2018-05-15 14:28:27 ERROR TaskSetManager:70 - Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
    2018-05-15 14:28:27 ERROR SparkHadoopWriter:91 - Aborting job job_20180515142827_0007.
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 4, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Ljava/lang/String;JJJI)Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;
            at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Native Method)
            at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileOutputStreamWithMode(NativeIO.java:559)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:219)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:398)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:804)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:123)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapRedWriteConfigUtil.initWriter(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:224)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:118)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:79)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

    Driver stacktrace:
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1587)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
            at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1586)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
            at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:257)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:831)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1820)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1769)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1758)
            at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:642)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2027)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2048)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2080)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1096)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1094)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1094)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1094)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1067)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1032)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1032)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1032)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:958)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:958)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:958)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:957)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(RDD.scala:1493)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1472)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1472)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
            at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1472)
            at $line30.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:26)
            at $line30.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:31)
            at $line30.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:33)
            at $line30.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:35)
            at $line30.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:37)
            at $line30.$read$$iw$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:39)
            at $line30.$read$$iw$$iw.<init>(<console>:41)
            at $line30.$read$$iw.<init>(<console>:43)
            at $line30.$read.<init>(<console>:45)
            at $line30.$read$.<init>(<console>:49)
            at $line30.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
            at $line30.$eval$.$print$lzycompute(<console>:7)
            at $line30.$eval$.$print(<console>:6)
            at $line30.$eval.$print(<console>)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:786)
            at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request.loadAndRun(IMain.scala:1047)
            at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:638)
            at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest$$anonfun$loadAndRunReq$1.apply(IMain.scala:637)
            at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
            at scala.reflect.internal.util.AbstractFileClassLoader.asContext(AbstractFileClassLoader.scala:19)
            at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$WrappedRequest.loadAndRunReq(IMain.scala:637)
            at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:569)
            at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain.interpret(IMain.scala:565)
            at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.interpretStartingWith(ILoop.scala:807)
            at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.command(ILoop.scala:681)
            at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.processLine(ILoop.scala:395)
            at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.loop(ILoop.scala:415)
            at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(ILoop.scala:923)
            at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
            at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop$$anonfun$process$1.apply(ILoop.scala:909)
            at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:97)
            at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.ILoop.process(ILoop.scala:909)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.doMain(Main.scala:76)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:56)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.JavaMainApplication.start(SparkApplication.scala:52)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:879)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:197)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:227)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:136)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
    Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Ljava/lang/String;JJJI)Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;
            at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Native Method)
            at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileOutputStreamWithMode(NativeIO.java:559)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:219)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:398)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:804)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:123)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapRedWriteConfigUtil.initWriter(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:224)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:118)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:79)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
      at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.write(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:96)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1096)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1094)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopDataset$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1094)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopDataset(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1094)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1067)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1032)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$4.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1032)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:1032)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(PairRDDFunctions.scala:958)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:958)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$saveAsHadoopFile$1.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:958)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.saveAsHadoopFile(PairRDDFunctions.scala:957)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply$mcV$sp(RDD.scala:1493)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1472)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$saveAsTextFile$1.apply(RDD.scala:1472)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:363)
      at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.saveAsTextFile(RDD.scala:1472)
      ... 49 elided
    Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 3.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.0 in stage 3.0 (TID 4, localhost, executor driver): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Ljava/lang/String;JJJI)Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;
            at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Native Method)
            at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileOutputStreamWithMode(NativeIO.java:559)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:219)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem$LocalFSFileOutputStream.<init>(RawLocalFileSystem.java:209)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.createOutputStreamWithMode(RawLocalFileSystem.java:307)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:296)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.create(RawLocalFileSystem.java:328)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSOutputSummer.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:398)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:461)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.create(ChecksumFileSystem.java:440)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:911)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.create(FileSystem.java:804)
            at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextOutputFormat.getRecordWriter(TextOutputFormat.java:123)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapRedWriteConfigUtil.initWriter(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:224)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$.org$apache$spark$internal$io$SparkHadoopWriter$$executeTask(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:118)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:79)
            at org.apache.spark.internal.io.SparkHadoopWriter$$anonfun$3.apply(SparkHadoopWriter.scala:78)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:87)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:109)
            at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:345)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: Did you set up your hadoop home and add the bin in your PATH ?

Comment: HADOOP_HOME = C:\hadoop\hadoop-3.1.0

JAVA_HOME = C:\java\jdk1.8.0_172

JDK_HOME = C:\java\jdk1.8.0_172

JRE_HOME = C:\java\jre1.8.0_172

Path = "C:\java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin; C:\java\jre1.8.0_172\bin; C:\hadoop\hadoop-3.1.0\bin; C:\scala\bin; C:\Spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\bin\"

Comment: And do you have the %HADOOP_HOME%/bin in your PATH env variable ?

Comment: yeah, I have "C:\hadoop\hadoop-3.1.0\bin" in PATH

Comment: Do you have hadoop.dll and winutils.exe in this directory ?

Comment: of course yes. Actually, if I don't have these files and env variables, I could not run "spark-shell". But I ran it successfully and entered scala env. After running previous scala command on CMD, they worked, until the last command counts.saveAsTextFile("output")

Comment: Instead of output can you give absolute path like c:\users\test\output

Comment: tried, but still got the same issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to specify the input file path correctly. Your input RDD is not getting created that's why its not able to create an output.

You should see as below:-

```scala
scala> val inputfile = sc.textFile("file:///home/lg552987/input.txt")

inputfile: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = file:///home/lg552987/input.txt MapPartitionsRDD[5] at textFile at <console>:27

scala> val counts = inputfile.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).map(word => (word, 1)).reduceByKey(_+_)

counts: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)] = ShuffledRDD[8] at reduceByKey at <console>:29

scala> counts.toDebugString

res0: String =
(2) ShuffledRDD[8] at reduceByKey at <console>:29 []
 +-(2) MapPartitionsRDD[7] at map at <console>:29 []
    |  MapPartitionsRDD[6] at flatMap at <console>:29 []
    |  file:///home/lg552987/input.txt MapPartitionsRDD[5] at textFile at <console>:27 []
    |  file:///home/lg552987/input.txt HadoopRDD[4] at textFile at <console>:27 []

scala> counts.cache()

res1: counts.type = ShuffledRDD[8] at reduceByKey at <console>:29

scala> counts.saveAsTextFile("output")
```

```sh
$ hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://NNPOCHA/user/502552987/output

Found 3 items
-rw-r--r--   3 502552987 hdfs          0 2018-08-02 16:46 hdfs://NNPOCHA/user/502552987/output/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   3 502552987 hdfs         36 2018-08-02 16:46 hdfs://NNPOCHA/user/502552987/output/part-00000
-rw-r--r--   3 502552987 hdfs         14 2018-08-02 16:46 hdfs://NNPOCHA/user/502552987/output/part-00001
```

Answer (score 4):

From the Error logs. seems like you are using Spark on Windows. You can try for below troubleshooting steps:-

> 1. search for winuntils.exe path
> 2. cd path
> 3. winutils.exe chmod 777 output (directory where you store output)
> 4. Lets try again to store output (`counts.saveAsTextFile("output")`)