# Spark throws error when trying to save a CSV file

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql

Community wizards,

I am really frustrated. When it comes to Spark, Hadoop et al., nothing seems to be straightforward.

For the past hours, I tried to find a solution to the following issue:

```
ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 13.0 (TID 823)
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.createFileWithMode0(Ljava/lang/String;JJJI)Ljava/io/FileDescriptor;
```

**Versions**:

1. OS: Windows 10
2. Spark version: 2.4.6
3. Scala version: 2.11.12
4. Hadoop version: 2.7.1
5. Java version: 1.8.0_202 (64-bit)

**Variables**:

1. SPARK_HOME: C:\Spark
2. HADOOP_HOME: C:\Hadoop\hadoop-2.7.1
3. SCALA_HOME: C:\Program Files (x86)\scala
4. JRE_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_202
5. JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_202

**Paths**:

1. %SPARK_HOME%\bin
2. %HADOOP_HOME%\bin
3. %SCALA_HOME%\bin
4. %JRE_HOME%\bin
5. %JAVA_HOME%\bin

The command that throws the error is:

```
df.coalesce(1).write.format("csv").save("result")
```

The folder (result) seems to be created, but it's empty.

I have literally no idea how to solve this issue.

Any help would be warmly welcomed.

Comment: The following post might help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344874/spark-scala-saveastextfile-exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your `HADOOP_HOME=C:\Hadoop\hadoop-2.7.1` is pointed to Hadoop Binaries/Libraries, instead you should need a tool called  `WINUTILS.EXE` to work in Windows.

You can  download Hadoop Version of winutils from git and map HADOOP_HOME to Root directory of Winutils.
https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils

**Source:**

From Hadoop's Confluence:
Hadoop requires native libraries on Windows to work properly -that includes to access the file:// filesystem, where Hadoop uses some Windows APIs to implement posix-like file access permissions

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/HADOOP2/WindowsProblems

Comment: I already had the `winutils.exe` inside `C:\Hadoop\hadoop-2.7.1\bin`. I took this [bin](https://github.com/steveloughran/winutils/tree/master/hadoop-2.7.1) folder and replaced it with the one I already had and it worked. Seems that `winutils.exe` wasn't the real issue, but some other thing surely was. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue.
The solution that did a magic for me is - you need to download a bin folder for respective hadoop version that you are using.Once downloaded , replace the old bin folder with new one and replace the winutil.exe inside hadoop/bin/winutil.exe.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow Kanika. I believe your answer is covered by the accepted answer by Feroz. Please review existing answers before posting a new one as Stackoverflow aims to not have duplicate answers to Questions.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you don't have [Hadoop binaries](https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils) for Windows installed in `HADOOP_HOME` directory.
Or it could be that their dependencies (such as Visual C++ Runtime) are missing.

You also might need to load shared libraries directly, it depends on the way you start your Spark application.

```
System.load(System.getenv("HADOOP_HOME") + "/lib/hadoop.ddl");
```