# Getting an error while trying to run an Apache Spark example on Windows

Tags: apache-spark

My setup:

spark version 3.1.2

hadoop version 3.2 (pre built for apache hadoop 3.2 and later)

scala version 2.12.10

java version 1.8

Installed the Apache Spark archive file to C:\Users\anime\ApacheSpark\spark.

SPARK_HOME C:\Users\anime\ApacheSpark\spark

HADOOP_HOME C:\Users\anime\ApacheSpark\hadoop

Copied Hadoop.dll and winutils.exe from [here](https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils/tree/master/hadoop-3.2.0/bin) to %HADOOP_HOME%/bin

I am running the following few lines of code as example from command line starting at
C:\Users\anime\ApacheSpark

`

```
val textFile = sc.textFile("spark/README.md")

val tokens = textFile.flatMap(l=>l.split(" "))

val cp = tokens.map(word=>(word, 1))

val counts = cp.reduceByKey((a, n)=>a+n)

val sortedCounts = counts.sortBy(kvpair=>kvpair._2, false)

sortedCounts.saveAsTextFile("NewFolder")
```

`

I get a long error log as

**ERROR SparkHadoopWriter: Aborting job job_202107261357425367869624572589035_0010.
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z..**

Things I have tried:

1. Copied hadoop.dll to C:\Windows\System32
2. Ran winutils.exe chmod 777 NewFolder following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50344874/spark-scala-saveastextfile-exception)

Can anyone help me on getting my first example working? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue. Double check your environment variables and winutils version.

[Docs](https://github.com/cdarlint/winutils#how-to-use)

```
HADOOP_HOME=<your local hadoop-ver folder>
PATH=%PATH%;%HADOOP_HOME%\bin
```